# How to fill mongo Db table by C# Driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am not an expert of nosql but a year ago I created a mongodb table by using below code:

```
        const string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

            // Create a MongoClient object by using the connection string
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

            ////Use the MongoClient to access the server
            var database = client.GetDatabase("YUSUF");

            ////get mongodb collection
            var collection = database.GetCollection("expressions");
            var expression = new Expression { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),ExpressionSentence = "Test",Name = "yusuf",CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,Status = true };
            collection.InsertOneAsync(expression);
    public class Expression {

        [BsonId]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ExpressionSentence { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }


    }
```

Today above codes is doing nothing now. Not working also not throwing any error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it seems that you didn't use connection string when creating new MongoClient(). And check the C# MongoDB Driver have to be latest version.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void insert()
    {
        var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase("YUSUF");


       var collection = database.GetCollection<Expression>("expressions");
          var expression = new Expression { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),ExpressionSentence = "Test",Name = "yusuf",CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,Status = true };
        collection.InsertOneAsync(expression);
    }

 public class Expression {

    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ExpressionSentence { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }


}
```

have to work with the latest C# MongoDB Driver.

**MY METHOD**

```
static void insert()
    {
        var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase("fairytale");

        // var unicorns = database.GetCollection("unicorns");
        var unicorns = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("unicorns");

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 5000)
        {
            var document = new BsonDocument
            {
                {"name",GenerateRandomUnicornName()},
                {"horns",Random.Next(50)},
                {"likes",new BsonArray{ "apple", "onion" }},

            };

            unicorns.InsertOneAsync(document);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i used before :  var client = new MongoClient(connectionString); it is working...

Comment: Why do i need async? without async task , can i do that ?

Comment: I'm updating my solution. I'm adding my sample insert method which I used in a short time ago.

Comment: I think your problem is about for type of document. Your collection have to be Expression. I adapted your method. Also I'm adding my working method.  My method works well. Sorry for wrong asnwer.